# is static method safe for this case?

Tags: java, jsf

In my web jsf application, I display different messages to the user using this method:

```
private void showErrorMessage(final String message) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
            new FacesMessage(message));
}
```

which is located in each bean which requires to warn user in some way.

Now, I want to apply **DRY** rule and to make a static class with this showErrorMessage method to be a static one, but I am not sure if this will be safe... I mean **static method vs instance of a faces context** based on session, can this produce conflicts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods are not safe when they use mutable variables which can be changed from outside. E.g.

```
private static String foo; // +getter +setter

public static void foo() {
    // Do something with foo.
}
```

This is not threadsafe. A race condition can occur when other thread changes `foo` while the current thread is inside `foo()`. Yours, however, don't use any externally mutable variables. Everything is declared and used methodlocal/threadlocal. So it's safe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure how the current instance is returned but I bet a ThreadLocal is used and thus you should be fine with a static method. It's basically just a convenience method for an existing call to the static `getCurrentInstance()` method.

Answer (score 1):

That particular static method is perfectly safe.

getCurrentInstance() returns a thread-local FacesContext object.  FacesContext encapsulates the state related to the request that the current thread is processing.  Another thread would be processing a different request, and would get a different FacesContext instance.